# Logstash output to https

Tags: logstash

i have logstash running on windows 8.1
the output is set to https address. wich is hosted on windows server 2012 r2.
when the request gets to the server it gets rejected. this is what i get from logstash:

```html
←[33mUnhandled exception {:request=><FTW::Request(@13468) @headers=FTW::HTTP::He
aders <{"host"=>"taasukaesb.ewavetest.co.il", "connection"=>"keep-alive", "conte
nt-type"=>"application/json", "content-length"=>517}> @method="POST" @body="{\"A
ctivityTime\":\"2015-08-25T08:48:11.691Z\",\"LogType\":\"Info\",\"ServiceName\":
\"Portal.Nlog2Esbtest\",\"Context\":\"Portal\",\"UserId\":\"8664e362-f63d-4d10-8
a23-3b86b9f22cc7\",\"LogSubType\":\"Info\",\"TransactionCode\":\"5d14a403-a566-4
9ab-b8bc-a40c999eebe5\",\"Servers\":\"SlavaNili\",\"ServiceId\":\"8664e362-f63d-
4d10-8a23-3b86b9f22cc7\",\"RequestIPs\":\"172.19.5.8\",\"EntityClass\":\" \",\"M
ethods\":\"Button2_Click\",\"SourceFilePath\":\" \",\"SourceLineNum\":34,\"Title
\":\"TEST INFO\",\"Details\":\"this is a test to tell that something happend, bu
t its cool..\"}" @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0816b0 @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x
192e6ba1 @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x306a119a>, @metrics={}, @channel=#<Cabin::Chann
el:0xd0816b0 ...>>, @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0x7fd74c77>, @level=:info, @subscri
bers={}, @data={}> @request_uri="/TaasukaService.svc/TransactionLog/CreateJson?C
ontext=Portal&UserToken=a441b37f-3403-43fd-8f58-d1da3024133a" @version=1.1 @port
=443 @protocol="https" >, :response=>nil, :exception=>#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>, :stacktrace=>["o
rg/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:195:in `connect_nonblock'", "C:/logstash/ins
tall/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.44/lib/ftw/connection.rb:413:in `do_se
cure'", "C:/logstash/install/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.44/lib/ftw/con
nection.rb:393:in `secure'", "C:/logstash/install/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/f
tw-0.0.44/lib/ftw/agent.rb:449:in `connect'", "C:/logstash/install/vendor/bundle
/jruby/1.9/gems/ftw-0.0.44/lib/ftw/agent.rb:283:in `execute'", "C:/logstash/inst
all/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-http-1.0.0/lib/logstash/outputs
/http.rb:126:in `receive'", "C:/logstash/install/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/lo
gstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:88:in `handle'", "(eval):83:
in `output_func'", "C:/logstash/install/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-co
re-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:244:in `outputworker'", "C:/logstash/inst
all/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.
rb:166:in `start_outputs'"], :level=>:warn}←[0m
```

notice the ssl error.
now this serivce is fine and accessible. works with no problem from this computer. but only when setting the output in logstash to HTTPS this happens.
this is a follow up from this post:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-output-to-https/27946/3 
that no one in elastic answerd.

thanks for any help.